# How to create if-else loop near #import sttatement to check the Device Type (iPad/iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) to create SplitView in my app. In `PKRevealController.m` file i am giving the value to how much screen will reveal using this code

```
#define DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE NSMakeRange(273, 310)
```

This is for iPhone but now i want to make loop to select the size. if device is iPad than large else small so how can i do this because its outside of `@interface PKRevealController`

I have check some code on google and i find like this

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_6_0) || defined(__MAC_10_8)
#define AF_CAST_TO_BLOCK id
#else
#define AF_CAST_TO_BLOCK __bridge void *
```

So can i create something like this for selecting device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to achive this change value according to your need

In your PKRevealController.m

```
#define DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPad NSMakeRange(700, 700)

#define DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPhone NSMakeRange(273, 310)

#define DEFAULT_RIGHT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPad DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPad
#define DEFAULT_RIGHT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPhone DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPhone
```

And in iterface find out `setup` method an replace it with this method

## pragma mark - Setup

```
- (void)setup
{
    self.state = PKRevealControllerFocusesFrontViewController;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //device is iPhone
        self.leftViewWidthRange = DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPhone;
        self.rightViewWidthRange = DEFAULT_RIGHT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPhone;
    }
    else
    {
        //device is iPad
        self.leftViewWidthRange = DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPad;
        self.rightViewWidthRange = DEFAULT_RIGHT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_iPad;
    }
   
    
    self.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
}
```

Than it should be work..:)

Comment: Not worked its only set it for iPad and for iPhone Display blank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is a way to do that, usually problem like that is solved by making 2 #define statements, like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_IPHONE NSMakeRange(273, 310)
#define DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_IPAD NSMakeRange(273, 310)
```

and then when you have to use it in code just check the device type like this:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    /* code that uses DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_IPAD */
}
else {
    /* code that uses DEFAULT_LEFT_VIEW_WIDTH_RANGE_IPHONE */
}
```